# CORS error despite using cross origin, advice?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, debugging, cors

I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

I'm building a restaurant app and I have a problem with cors. As I get the message above. It might be something to do with post because I have enabled cross-origin at the food controller.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import JSOG from "jsog";
export function Food(props){
    let [name,setName]=useState("");
    let[description,setDescription]=useState("");
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
    let [price,setPrice]=useState(0);
        let initialize=(id)=>{
            if(props.id){
            let path='http://localhost:8080/food/'+this.props.id;
             axios.get(path)
                 .then(res => {
                    let target="";
                    target = JSOG.stringify(res.data);
                    let newObject= JSOG.parse(target);
                    let food=newObject;
                    setName(food.name);
                    setDescription(food.description);
                    setSelectedImage(food.url);
                    setPrice(food.price);

               }).catch(
               function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });}
        }
        //this function
        let submit=async(event)=>{
            event.preventDefault();
            let path="http://localhost:8080/food";
            if(!props.id){
              await  axios.post(
                    path,{name:name,description:description,url:selectedImage,price:price})
                    .then(res => {
                        
                    }).catch(
                    function (error) {
                    console.log(error.toString());
                    });
            }
            else{
                path+="/exist";
                axios.post(
                    path,{ id: props.id ,name:name,description:description,url:selectedImage.name,price:price})
                    .then(res => {
                        
                    }).catch(
                    function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    });
            }
           
        }
        useEffect(() => {
        if(props.id){
            initialize(props.id);
        }});
let Remove=async()=>{
    if(props.id)
    await axios.delete('http://localhost:8080/food/'+props.id).catch(
        function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
    return(<div>
        <form onSubmit={submit} >
             <img src={selectedImage} alt="no image" />
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="title" >Title:</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title" onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}} value={name}/>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label htmlFor="description" >Description:</label>
                <input type="text" id="description" name="description" onChange={(e)=>{setDescription(e.target.value)}} value={description}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="url" >Url:</label>
               
                <input
                    type="file"
                    name="url"
                    onChange={(event) => {
                    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
                    setSelectedImage(event.target.files[0]);
                    }}
                /> </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="price" >Price:</label>
                <input type="number" id="" name="price" onChange={(e)=>{setPrice(e.target.value)}} value={price}/>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            
        </form>
        <button onClick={Remove} >Remove</button></div>
    );


}
```

```
my controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/food")
@CrossOrigin
public class FoodController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Autowired
    FoodServices foodServices;
    @Autowired
    JasyptConfig jasyptConfig;




    @GetMapping
    public List<Food> getfoods() {
        return foodServices.getfoods();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Food getfood(@PathVariable Long id) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Food food=foodServices.getFoodById(id);
        return food;
    }
    @GetMapping("/byName/{name}")
    public Food getfoodByName(@PathVariable String name) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Food food=foodServices.getFoodByName(name);
        return food;
    }
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity createfood(@RequestParam  String name,@RequestParam  String description,@RequestParam  String url,@RequestParam  float price) throws URISyntaxException {
        Food food=new Food(name,description,url,price);
        foodServices.saveFood(food);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
    @PostMapping("/exist")
    public ResponseEntity createfood(@RequestParam  long id,@RequestParam  String name,@RequestParam  String description,@RequestParam  String url,@RequestParam  float price) throws URISyntaxException {
        Food food=foodServices.getFoodById(id);
        food.setName(name);
        food.setDescription(description);
        food.setUrl(url);
        food.setPrice(price);
        foodServices.saveFood(food);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity deletefood(@PathVariable Long id) {
        foodServices.removeFood(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

As I said I added cross origins and tried debugging. I also looked at videos and tutorials; but, they all say the same thing. My best theory is it has something to do with post.

For further reference the links to my front and backend side:
for front end: https://github.com/JonathanDaboush/divinaPopinaFrontEnd.git
for back:
https://github.com/JonathanDaboush/DivinaPopinaBackEnd.git

Answer (score 0):

This is because you did not specify the orgins so you should specify where it should authorize so give
`@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` for full access or `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http//apis/")` for any specific website or apis you access

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a security concept that allows restricting the resources implemented in web browsers. It prevents the JavaScript code producing or consuming the requests against different origin.

your web application is running on 8080 port and by using JavaScript you are trying to consuming RESTful web services from 9090 port. Under such situations, you will face the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing security issue on your web browsers.

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.